# Data processing List of dict without using libraries or import

Tags: python

I'm studying data processing in python with apply Count, Sum, Group, Sort on a list of dict

```
list_data = [
              {"name": "milk", "quantity": 1, "price_of_one": 2000},
              {"name": "egg", "quantity": 12, "price_of_one": 500},
              {"name": "egg", "quantity": 6, "price_of_one": 500},
              {"name": "milk", "quantity": 2, "price_of_one": 2000},
              {"name": "meat", "quantity": 1, "price_of_one": 10000}
            ]
```

I want to handle this list with the expected result:

```
list_data = [
              {"name": "egg", "quantity": 18, "total": 9000, "number_occurrences": 2},
              {"name": "milk", "quantity": 3, "total": 6000, "number_occurrences": 2},
              {"name": "meat", "quantity": 1, "total": 10000, "number_occurrences": 1}
            ]
```

As seen, I need SUM by "quantity", SUM by "quantity*price_of_one", GROUP by "name", SORT by SUM of quantity and COUNT number occurrences.

I don't know How do I make it right?. Is there any way I can get the expected result?

Comment: What happens to `ID`? Is it simply discarded as you seem to group by name?

Comment: @NelsonGon you right, maybe ID not need to be here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault)/[`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get):

```
out = {}
for d in list_data:
    d2 = out.setdefault(d['name'], {'name': d['name']})
    d2['quantity'] = d2.get('quantity', 0) + d['quantity']
    d2['total'] = d2.get('total', 0) + d['quantity']*d['price_of_one']
    d2['number_occurrences'] = d2.get('number_occurrences', 0)+1

out = list(out.values())
```

output:

```
[{'name': 'milk', 'quantity': 3, 'total': 6000, 'number_occurrences': 2},
 {'name': 'egg', 'quantity': 18, 'total': 9000, 'number_occurrences': 2},
 {'name': 'meat', 'quantity': 1, 'total': 10000, 'number_occurrences': 1},
]
```

##### sorted output:

```
out = sorted(out, key=lambda x: (x['quantity'], x['number_occurrences']),
             reverse=True)
```

output:

```
[{'name': 'egg', 'quantity': 18, 'total': 9000, 'number_occurrences': 2},
 {'name': 'milk', 'quantity': 3, 'total': 6000, 'number_occurrences': 2},
 {'name': 'meat', 'quantity': 1, 'total': 10000, 'number_occurrences': 1}]
```

Comment: oh, you're so good, I didn't know python could be like this. See, .setdefault I don't know about this. I need to learn more, thanks

Comment: I added a few improvements